# What is bad about this schema?

Tags: mysql, database, schema, convention

I have created some tables that is going to be used for Router activity reporting.

Each table is a one to one copy of routers api command.
My question is, from design and convention point of view, what are bad about these tables? What should be changed about it and what I did wrong?
I know it is flat and not normalized, but apart from that.

Here are create statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `Hotspot_UserActivity` (
  `Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HotspotNameId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Server` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `User` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MacAddress` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Uptime` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SessionTimeLeft` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IdleTime` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ByteIn` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ByteOut` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PacketIn` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PacketOut` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TimeCreated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

# Dump of table interface
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `interface` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mtu` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l2mtu` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_l2mtu` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mac_address` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tx_byte` int(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rx_byte` int(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tx_packet` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rx_packet` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rx_drop` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tx_drop` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rx_error` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tx_error` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


# Dump of table host_activity
# ------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `host_activity` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mac_address` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `server` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uptime` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idle_time` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bytes_in` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bytes_out` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packets_in` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packets_out` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



# Dump of table Hotspot
# ------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `Hotspot` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HotspotName` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Interface` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Profile` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IdleTimeOut` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `KeepAliveTimeOut` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProxyStatus` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Invalid` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Https` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Disabled` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


# Dump of table system_health
# ------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `system_health` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `temperature` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpuTemperature` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `powerConsumption` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `voltage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


# Dump of table system_resource
# ------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `system_resource` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uptime` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `free_memory` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_memory` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpu_count` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpu_frequency` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpu_load` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `free_hdd_space` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_hdd_space` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

# Dump of table user_activity
# ------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `user_activity` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uptime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bytes_in` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bytes_out` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packets_in` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packets_out` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad things:

- You are mixing `StudlyCase` and `snake_case` in field names
- You do not link tables using their primary keys (`Hotspot_UserActivity` contains user name for example, not his id)
- You have no indexes on tables
- You are using `latin1` charset and it will blow all unicode away
- Your tables probably have excessive surrogate primary keys (are you sure you cannot pick a good primary key for `system_health` table? May be you can encode a period of time somehow or use (`HotspotNameId`, `user_id`, `TimeCreated` / `PeriodId`) as primary key in `Hotspot_UserActivity`
- You are allowing too many fields to be nulls. Is that really necessary? Are you tables that sparse?
- You have probably poorly chosen types for some of your database fields. For example, I am pretty sure it's enough of 4 bytes `int` to represent `Uptime`. Why VARCHAR there?
- You are violating your own naming conventions there. For example, your `TimeCreated` field has `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clause. How is that? This is a `created_at` field, not `updated_at`.

Comment: Hi FractalizeR, Thank you for your reply, it is very helpful, and I will follow them. Only about uptime, it is a string like this: 4w3d2h3m4s, that is why it is VARCHAR. One last question, what is the most used convention for Table names and field name. Is pascal case good for both?

Comment: @user1322977 It's a matter of taste, I think. But i've seen mostly snake_case.